# Access others have to separate boards associated with different organizations

Tags: trello

I want to invite someone to view a board I created. Will they see the other boards I created that are attached to a different organization?  I've been testing with secondary email address and I can access everything.

Answer (score 1):

Visibility level: Organization:

> This board is visible to members of the organization. Only those
>   invited to the board can edit. The board must be part of an org to
>   enabled this.

Any user who's a member of an organization can see all boards, but they shouldn't be able to see boards in other organizations unless they're also members of that organization.
Additionally, if you mark a board within an organization as **private** then only invited users can see that board (this is what one of my colleagues does for his personal board within the organization I created for our company).

It looks like you can mix'n'match board visibilities (not sure to what extent), best to try it and see what works for you.